# C Array change causing variable modification

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, ubuntu-9.04

I am trying to modify a value in an array using the C programming language and I seem to be hitting a blank wall with this seemingly easy operation. Please see code snippet below:

```
while(1) {
        printf("Current prime candidate is %i\n",nextPrimeCandidate);
        int innerSieve;//=2;
        int currentPrimeCandidate=0;

        for (innerSieve=2;innerSieve<SIEVELIMIT;innerSieve++) {
            currentPrimeCandidate = nextPrimeCandidate * innerSieve;
            //printf("Inner Sieve  is b4 funny place %i,%i\n",innerSieve,currentPrimeCandidate);

            //initArray[currentPrimeCandidate]=5;
            //VERY UNIQUE LINE
            myArray[currentPrimeCandidate] = 0;



            //printf("Inner Sieve after funny place is %i,%i \n",innerSieve,currentPrimeCandidate);

        }
        nextPrimeCandidate=getNextPrimeCandidate(myArray,++nextPrimeCandidate);
        if ((nextPrimeCandidate^2) > SIEVELIMIT ) break;

    }
```

The problem is with the line highlighted with the `VERY UNIQUE LINE` comment. For some reason, when the innerSieve variable reaches 33 and gets to that line, it sets the contents of the innerSieve variable to the value of that line ( which currently is 0) and basically forces the loop into an infinite loop( the `SIEVELIMIT` variable is set at 50). It seems that there is some funny stuff going on in the registers when I checked using the Eclipse Debug facility but I am not too sure what I should be looking for.

If you need the whole code listing, this can be provided.( with a particular variable which is not yet initialised in the code being initialised at the precise point that the innerSieve variable hits 32)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what does `if ((nextPrimeCandidate^2) > SIEVELIMIT ) break;` means?

Comment: I apparently was trying to check if `nextPrimeCandidate` raised to the power of 2 was greater than `SIEVELIMIT` but after reading Adam Rosenfields answer below, I should really forget my JAVA experience when dealing with C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guessing that `currentPrimeCandidate` is greater than the maximum index of `myArray`, and you're overwriting `innerSieve` (which likely follows `myArray` on the stack).

Comment: Yep, in your inner loop try limiting by `SIEVE_LIMIT` (that should be the actual length of the array!) the value of `currentPrimeCandidate` , and not of `innerSieve` .

Answer (score 4):

@ruslik hit on it in the comment.  The problem is this line:

```
if ((nextPrimeCandidate^2) > SIEVELIMIT ) break;
```

In C, the `^` operator is **not** the power operator, it is the *bitwise xor* operator.  You're iterating far too many times than you intend, which is resulting in an array-index-out-of-bounds error, so you're overwriting random memory and getting strange results.

There is no power operator in C (though there is the [`pow`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pow) function).  Since you're just squaring a number, the simplest fix is to multiply the number by itself:

```
if ((nextPrimeCandidate * nextPrimeCandidate) > SIEVELIMIT ) break;
```

Comment: I actually did not know that C has no explicit power operator! I had actually fixed the problem with tomlogics answer but now that you have added this, I might need to go back and review what I did. Thanks!